# Moment generating function of $f(x)=1/c$

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Moment generating function of $f(x)=1/c$, $0<x<c$.

Well, I know the calculation is easy. $M_X(t) = \frac{1}{ct} (e^{tc}-1)$.

This question is Exercise 2.30 (a) Statistical Inference
Book by George Casella and Roger Lee Berger. However, by definition, we need to discuss the existence of $M_X(t)$. We need to guarantee that the expectation $E e^{tX}$ exists for t in some neighborhood of 0. Obviously, in this question, t cannot be 0. Because if t=0, then mgf doesn't exist. Am I correct?

Comment: If you write out the series for $e^{tc}-1,$ you see all terms have $tc$ as a factor. So one *can* divide by it.

Comment: $e^{tX}=1$ when $t=0$ so $M_X(t)=1$ for $t=0$, as is the case for any random variable $X$.

Comment: I see. So I don't need to worry about t=0 at all.